# How to get the request URL on application startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to find the request URL (the domain specifically) when the application starts, in my Startup.cs file..

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   Configuration = new Configuration().AddEnvironmentVariables();
   string url = "";
}
```

I need it in the Startup.cs file because it will determine what transient services are added later in the startup class, in the ConfigureServices method.

What is the correct way of getting this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly you are unable to retrieve the hosting URL of your application since that bit is controlled by IIS/WebListener etc. and doesn't flow through to the application directly.

Now a nice alternative is to provide each of your servers with an `ASPNET_ENV` environment variable to then separate your logic. Here's some examples on how to use it:

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Will only get called if there's no method that is named Configure{ASPNET_ENV}.
    }

    public void ConfigureDev(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Will get called when ASPNET_ENV=Dev
    }
}
```

---

Here's another example when ASPNET_ENV=Dev and we want to do class separation instead of method separation:

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Wont get called.
    }

    public void ConfigureDev(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Wont get called
    }
}
```

**StartupDev.cs**

```
public class StartupDev // Note the "Dev" suffix
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Would only get called if ConfigureDev didn't exist.
    }

    public void ConfigureDev(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Will get called.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is helpful (albeit disappointing) however I decided to go another route for my issue.

Comment: or stick with one `Configure` method and just check the value of `env.EnvironmentName` with a good old if statement

Answer (score 3):

This won't give you the domain but may help if you're just running on a port and need access to that:

```
        var url = app.ServerFeatures.Get<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Features.IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses.Single();
```

Not sure what happens if you have multiple addresses bound.

Comment: Regarding this, bear in mind that for Azure (and I imagine not only), the local information is retrieved, not the externally available domain.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver it doesn't work anymore in asp.net core 2.xx. Struggling with any other way to get the hosting url. I am hoping to get the hosting url either kestra's or IIS's (i.e on dev it will be something like http://localhost:5000 and prod it will be whatever domain we have setup and IISIntegration will set that url)

Comment: @Nexus23 I’ve done very little with core but when I faced this problem I think I had to ‘cheat’ and put in config what the external domain is so it would read the config itself. I’m sure there’s a cleverer way too.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver could you please share that cheat, I could live with that if that works for now :)

Comment: This is not working, always the same result: Startup 127.0.0.1:XXX