# Migrate MVC 5 to MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I just wanted to know if there is any auto migration tool available to update from MVC5 to MVC6.

As they made some changed, like instead of `Global.asax`, there is a startup class.

I am using URL Rewriting and using `Global.asax` Application methods to achieve it.
Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tool out at the moment as MVC6 is still in beta. Your best bet would be to look at the [MVC project in git hub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) for examples.

Wrt to URL rewriting, you would probably be looking at:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SomeName",
        template: "SomeName/{action}/{type?}/{id?}"
}
```

which is place in this section:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
```

** update **

I don't think there is a way to get the request URL on startup - I asked a [similar question last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223565/how-to-get-the-request-url-on-application-startup). One way might be to use custom route constraints (I haven't tried this myself) but it looks like it could be what you need - [more info here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#custom-route-constraints) and [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/asp-net-mvc-6-attribute-routing-controller-action-tokens/). The way I did it for myself, was to look at the OnActionExecuted and OnActionExecuting events in my base controller.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am looking for alternate of Global.application_beginrequest

Comment: What do you need to do in it? Set a session variable or something else?

Comment: Here is check the requested URI, and call the needed route accordingly.
For eg: if request is from abc.com/about-us, I call route with templae: Article/{articleID} - where value or articleID depends on the requested URL. I manage all these from an XML file, therefore, list is way too long